pysnmp nextCmd is not defined
I have recently installed PySNMP library on Ubuntu.
When I run the following code :
    from pysnmp.hlapi import *
    def walk_Query_str(comm, IP, OID):
          query_str = []
          iterator = nextCmd(
          SnmpEngine(),
          CommunityData(comm, mpModel=1),
          UdpTransportTarget((IP, 161)),
          ContextData(),
          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(OID)),
          lexicographicMode=False
          )
          for errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds in iterator:
              if errorIndication:
                  print(errorIndication)
              elif errorStatus:
                  print('%s at %s' % (
                      errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                      errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'
                  ))
              else:
                  for varBind in varBinds:
                      query_str.append(varBind[1].prettyPrint())
          return query_str
#Inrow BC07       
walk_Query_str('fan@solar', '172.21.2.32', '1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.27.1.4.1.2.1.2.1')

this error shows up:

NameError: name 'nextCmd' is not defined


python version : python3.10
pip3 version : pip3.10
ubuntu : 22.04


I had the same error. The issue arose after I created a fresh Python venv with an update-to-date version of the pysnmp module. It looks like the current version 7.1.8 (https://pypi.org/project/pysnmp/7.1.8/) does not contain the nextCmd() method anymore.
Until I find a better fix, I am using a version which was working previously for me:
pysnmp==4.4.12
pyasn1==0.4.8

